# Specialized tri-spoke rear wheel free hub replacement?

Tags: hub, rear-wheel, freehub

I'm looking to replace the free hub on my Specialized tri-spoke rear wheel.

Can't seem to find a model number,and would love to put an 11-speed free hub.
Hope for some help?

Comment: All I found was references to a "HED" rear axle.   What size cassette is there now ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the hub you have in the Tri-spoke, you could just simply replace the freehub body to an 11-speed. E.g. Campagnolo makes an 11-speed freehub body shich is compatible with Shimano Hyperglide. Search for Campagnolo FH-BUU015 and you should find quite good deals on it.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you work out the compatibility options if you know the number of sprockets on the current cassette and the make:
http://www.bikeradar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12905742

If it is Shimano you might still be in luck as I had a wheel with a 10-speed Shimano cassette that turned out to have a spacer - it was an 11-speed hub with a 10-speed cassette fitted.